# Opportunity Access issue in Aura component after Summer'22 release

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, aura, summer-22

After summer'22 release, our community homepage is not rendering properly. After looking into the issue, we feel that it is related to Opportunity object access for "Customer Community Login" license user.

Here is the simplified component.

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes"
                access="Global" >
    <aura:attribute name="updatedOpportunity1" type="Opportunity" description="Variable to store application details"/>
    Hello
</aura:component>
```

We have added above component in a community page.

- On accessing the page from a Summer'22 env., it does not show the text "Hello"
- However, same works if we access it from a non Summer'22 org.

Could anyone take a look and suggest what has been changed in this release?

Comment: Do you see any error incase of Summer'22 org?

Comment: No Error on page or in browser console, it's just not display anything

Comment: It is working now. Home page is rendering in all affected enviroment.Not changes from our side. How to know if SF has made any changes?

Comment: I did a quick repro with the provided component yesterday in my Summer'22 and Spring'22 Dev orgs but couldn't replicate the reported behavior in my Summer'22. I've also checked if there are other customers who faced this but couldn't find any. So not sure if it is release-related and I am unable to suggest at the moment.